# Splitting $n^2$ objects into $n$ unordered groups

Tags: combinatorics

> Is there a way to prove that the number of ways to split up $n^2$ objects into $n$ unordered groups of size $n$ is $(((n^2)!)/((n!)^{(n+1)}))$

Question arises from: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2019_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_25

I tried to solve it using summation but that didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's just a multinomial coefficient. check the power in the denominator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Solve the problem for labeled groups first, then account for the fact that the groups are not labeled.

Comment: Ethan Bolker How would that help

Comment: @JeffersonJi: It is essentially what Hagen did in his solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do such a split up is to fill an $n\times n$ matrix with the $n^2$ objects in random order and then take the rows as subsets (and clearly every split up into $n$ groups of $n$ is obtainable this way).
There are $(n^2)!$ different orderings of the $n^2$ objects, but many lead to the same split-up: We can reorder each row in itself without changing the outcome, thus dividing the count by $n!$. As this applies to $n$ rows, we divide $n$ times, i.e., we divide by $n!^n$. Finally, the order of the rows is unimportant, i.e., we need to divide by yet another factor of $n!$. Final result:
$$\frac{(n^2)!}{n!^{n+1}}. $$